# How to get a new dataframe based on a column containing list of lists with start, end indices?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following dataframe. One of the columns is a list of lists containing the start, end index of the string (from the text) + some random label.

| No | Text | Labels |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples are the best. Banana is cool | [[0, 6, Apple],[21, 27, Banana]] |
| 2 | Random text. | [0, 2, Stuff],[3,4,Stuff2]] |

I want to somehow create a new dataframe based on the labels, putting the start + end of the string (sequence) in a new row and with the label (Apple for example) on another column. Somehow to delimiter what's labeled and what's not based on the "Labels" column.

For example:

| No | Text | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples | Apple |
| 2 | are the best. | None |
| 3 | Banana | Banana |
| 4 | is cool | None |
| 5 | Ra | Stuff |
| 6 | n | Stuff2 |
| 7 | dom text. | None |

Answer (score 1):

You can apply your own function to keep track of the indices/labels in your text and explode the resulting df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Text': ['Apples are the best. Banana is cool', 'Random text.'],
        'Labels': [[[0, 6, 'Apple'], [21, 27, 'Banana']], [[0, 2, 'Stuff'], [3, 4, 'Stuff2']]]
    }
)

def extract_text(row):
    i = 0
    res_lst_text = []
    res_lst_lbl = []
    for lst in row['Labels']:
        start, end, lbl = lst
        if start > i:
            res_lst_text.append(row['Text'][i:start])
            res_lst_lbl.append(None)

        res_lst_text.append(row['Text'][start:end])
        res_lst_lbl.append(lbl)
        i = end

    if i < len(row['Text'])-1:
            res_lst_text.append(row['Text'][i:])
            res_lst_lbl.append(None)

    return pd.Series([res_lst_text, res_lst_lbl])

df_out = df.apply(extract_text, axis=1).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)
df_out.columns = ['Text', 'Label']
```

Output:

```
              Text   Label
0           Apples   Apple
1   are the best.     None
2           Banana  Banana
3          is cool    None
4               Ra   Stuff
5                n    None
6                d  Stuff2
7         om text.    None
```

Edit: adding df constructor for reproducibility